# Elasticsearch term query as mysql in clause?

Tags: elasticsearch

In mysql, we can Query as:`select * from table1 where (name,age) in (('joe',11),('jim',15));`

How can I achieve this in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine should with must bools.

Read more here https://www.elastic.co/blog/lost-in-translation-boolean-operations-and-filters-in-the-bool-query

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [{
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "name": "joe"
                    }
                }, {
                    "match": {
                        "age": "11"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }, {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "name": "jim"
                    }
                }, {
                    "match": {
                        "age": "15"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

}